# Slow Random Prime Generation

Tags: c++, cryptography

I am working on a fully homomorphic encryption scheme that requires the generation of very large prime numbers (i.e. 200 digits or more) and currently our method is the biggest bottleneck in our program.We are using Shoup's NTL library, projects we have referenced have used the same library and have had much faster run times.

The function below is used to choose a random prime number Q0 such that lowLimit < Q0 < limit. The library function RandomPrime comes from NTL, it requires a specific number of bits for which your returned prime requires to be represented in binary so I've used the other library function PickRandom which returns a random integer, then I use that integer to determine the number of bits for the prime.

This is by far our biggest run time bottleneck. Is anyone familiar with NTL or any other, more efficient methods of prime number generation?

```
ZZ chooseQ0(const ZZ &lowLimit, const long &lambda, const ZZ &productOfPrimes){
ZZ prime, limit, Two, i, Q0, temp, s, last, temp2;
Two = 2;
long bits;
long err = 10;

limit = power(Two, pow(lambda, 5))/productOfPrimes;
cout << "Q0 limit: " << limit << endl;

srand(time(NULL));
s = rand()%100;
SetSeed(s);
RePick:
temp = PickRandom(limit);
if(temp <= lowLimit){
    cout << "Repicked Q0-1" << endl;
    goto RePick;
}

cout << "Q0 Random Number: " << temp << endl;
redo:

bits = NumBits(temp);
RandomPrime(temp2, bits, err);
if(temp2 <= lowLimit || temp2 > limit){
    cout << "Repicked Q0-2" << endl;
    goto RePick;
}
cout<< "Q0: " << temp2<< endl;
return temp2;
}
```

Comment: You'll never ever want to call rand() in cryptographic code. Please use a proper random number generator.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck I find the `s = rand()%100` method even more amusing than the call to `rand` itself. :)

Comment: Ok... can you explain why?

Comment: @nhoughto [Watch this!](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: 1) Why do you use rejection instead of generating a random number between 0 and upperLimit-lowerLimit and then adding lowerLimit to the result? 2) Indendation, loops instead of goto, declaring variables as close as possible to first usage would improve the readability of your code.

Comment: Your "loops" are weird. Why is the second generator going to `RePick` whereas the `redo` label is never used.

Comment: What about using a cryptographic library? If you like C++ you may like [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/numthry_8h_source.html) for instance. Disclaimer I do not currently use Botan nor do I know the strength of the implementation of Botan.